# C# Combobox Selection

Tags: combobox, button

I am populating a combobox dropdown with node fields from an Xml document. I have that working. Now I have the text in the dropdown menu of the combobox. I want to be able to press a 'Go' button and use the selected text. What are the commands please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx) property of ComboBox. It will return a string containing the currently selected text (ie. the text of the currently selected item) of the combo box.

To handle this from a button press, add an [OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx) event handler to the button, and in this event handler get the SelectedText and do what you need with it.

Comment: How do I write that to a string value?

Comment: What do you mean? The SelectedText property is a string.

Answer (score 0):

During events, `cboMyCombo.SelectedText` may be null because its value has been cleared: "For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string." [read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx).

You may just want to try using `cboMyCombo.Text`